# Deploying Firebase and Node.js application results in error: Error: Parse Error in remoteconfig.template.json: Unexpected token 'i' at 1:1

Tags: node.js, firebase, web-hosting, firebase-hosting

I tried many things mentioned in this portal none worked hence posting the same.

I have created a web application using the Node.js and I am trying to host that application using the Firebase so it can be accessed by my Colleagues and try out the features. I followed the instruction provided by Firebase and ran the following commands:

1. Created a project in Firebase console
2. `npm install -g firebase-tools`
3. `firebase login`
4. `firebase init` (Selected `HOSTING` with spacebar and * sign appeared next to it)
5. I have a `public` folder with the `index.html` file within it.
6. `firebase deploy`

When I run the `firebase deploy` I get the following error:
[image]

I looked at some answers based on that everything seems to be fine for me:

My `firebase.json` file has following content:

```
    {
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  },
  "remoteconfig": {
    "template": "remoteconfig.template.json"
  }
}
```

Not sure what exactly is going wrong. Can someone please help me how to host the Node.js application in Firebase.

Comment: I tried deleting the `.firebaserc` and `firebase.json` file from the folder and started with the `firebase init` and that worked.

Comment: You can also just remove `remoteconfig` settings from `firebase.json` if it is not required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some trying I was able to resolve the issue, posting the same so it can be helpful to someone in the future:

1. I deleted `.firebaserc` and `firebase.json` file which are created during the previous `firebase init` from the project folder.
2. I started with the `firebase init` again and that worked.

Answer (score 4):

I think the solution is to add `{}` to the offending `remoteconfig` file and thus make it valid JSON. It is currently completely empty.

Comment: This is solution in my case